# "Lens not attached" error with Sigma lens on Nikon D3100

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100

I have a Nikon D3100 and my Sigma 100-300mm f/4 EX DG IF HSM lens will no longer attach to my camera, it just keeps saying “lens not attached”.

I've been using this lens since the beginning of the year with no issues and all my other lenses still connect.

I've already tried wiping it and making sure no connectors are stuck. What else can I try?

[image]

Comment: Did you apply a firmware update to your D3100 recently?

Comment: Also related: [“Lens not attached” appearing whenever I try to use my Nikkor 70-300mm?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/42234/15871)

Comment: As much as some might like to close this question as a duplicate of another, it is *not* a match for any of the candidates suggested so far. The problem does *not* involve a manual lens. The problem is *not necessarily* firmware incompatibility because lens used to work and other lenses that continue to work may also be third-party. The problem is *not* affecting multiple lenses, but *is* isolated to a single lens.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the problems [Kat notes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/100885/75526) (incompatible firmware or poor electronic contact), **it's *possible* the lens has been damaged**. Many lenses have ribbons that connect moving components. Lenses with very wide zoom ranges have components that move a great deal. Internal connections can be damaged or come loose even with only ordinary use.

It would be helpful to try the lens with another body. If it works, the likelihood that the lens is damaged is reduced.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you are seeing suggests there is a problem with the connection between the camera and lens.

#### If you have recently updated the camera's firmware:

This could explain why the lens has only recently stopped working on
your camera. As your lens is made by Sigma, rather than by Nikon, it
could be that Nikon have introduced a change which your lens does not
understand. This is one reason why some people will only recommend
purchasing lenses made by the same manufacturer as the camera. I
would not advise attempting to "roll back" the update, as this could
cause other issues.

It may be that Sigma can update the lens firmware to accommodate the Nikon update. As your lens does not appear to be compatible with the [Sigma USB dock](https://www.sigma-imaging-uk.com/product/sigma-usb-dock-2/) you would need to get in touch with Sigma support to enquire about this and/or arrange for the lens to be sent in. (NB: They may ask you to send the camera as well so they can confirm the update resolves the problem.)

#### If you have *not* updated the camera's firmware:

You could try [carefully cleaning the contacts on both the camera and the lens](https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/eu/BV_article?articleNo=000006511&configured=1&lang=en_GB) if you haven't already.

If this is not successful, you could send the lens in to Sigma's service department for diagnostics and repair (particularly if it is still under warranty), or you could take both the camera and lens to a local camera store to see if they can spot any problems with the lens mount which could be preventing it from connecting properly.